# Connection refused on socket.connect (Django app deployed on uWSGI + Nginx)

Tags: python, django, sockets, nginx, uwsgi

I have a Django application deployed on a VM using uWSGI & Nginx setup.
I would like to print some data, by passing the required information to a printer that is configured on the same network using a socket:

```
    printer_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    printer_socket.connect(('10.125.125.2', 9001))
    printer_socket.send(bytes(source='data', encoding='utf-8'))
```

*Note: the IP address and the port are here for illustration purposes.*

**Problem:** I get a Err 111 Connection refused error, however. The error is triggered at the printer_socket.connect step.

**Additional information:** The python code that initializes the socket, connects to the required IP address/Port and sends the data works fine when it's run from the python interactive shell.

**Question:** What do I need to configure in order to allow opening sockets from a django web application, deployed using uWSGI and Nginx?

*Please keep in mind that the configuration of the project is out of the scope of this question. I don't have troubles configuring the app. The app works fine. I am specifically interested in how to allow opening sockets from a web app, served using uWSGI + Nginx setup*

**UPDATE**
Here's the .ini configuration file for the uWSGI.

```
    [uwsgi]
    project = App
    uid = user
    base = /home/%(uid)

    chdir = %(base)/%(project)
    home = %(base)/Venv/%(project)
    module = %(project).wsgi:application
    # daemonize = %{base}/uwsgi/%{project}.log
    logto = /home/user/logs/uwsgi/%{project}.log

    master = true
    processes = 5

    socket = /run/uwsgi/%(project).sock
    chown-socket = %(uid):www-data
    chmod-socket = 777
    vacuum = true
    buffer-size=32768
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's your Python and uWSGI version? Also you should provide uWSGI config.

Comment: uWSGI, by default, doesn't block any outgoing connections (since you can connect to the database from the app). So it's likely that the problem is either in uWSGI config or permissions.

Comment: Python 3.5; uWSGI 2.0.13.1
Please check out the question, I have added the .ini configuration file.
Maybe you could point me to the config that I need to look at or the permissions that I need to set?